# Using VBA in excel to dynamically to insert check boxes and assign the Caption Values from a item list on a separate worksheet in the same workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Here is the code so far, when I run the code I get mismatch error.

How do I correct this error, all the examples I see on the internet do not address my use case.

```
 Sub CreateCheckBoxes()

'Declare variables
Dim c As Range
Dim chkBox As CheckBox
Dim ansBoxDefault As Long
Dim chkBoxRange As Range
Dim chkBoxDefault As Boolean

'Ingore errors if user clicks Cancel or X
On Error Resume Next

'Use Input Box to select cells
Set chkBoxRange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select cell range", _
    Title:="Create checkboxes", Type:=8)

'Exit the code if user clicks Cancel or X
If Err.Number <> 0 Then Exit Sub

'Use MessageBox to select checked or unchecked
ansBoxDefault = MsgBox("Should the boxes be checked?", vbYesNoCancel, _
    "Create checkboxes")
If ansBoxDefault = vbYes Then chkBoxDefault = True
If ansBoxDefault = vbNo Then chkBoxDefault = False
If ansBoxDefault = vbCancel Then Exit Sub

'Turn error checking back on
On Error GoTo 0

'Loop through each cell in the selected cells
For Each c In chkBoxRange

    'Create the checkbox
    Set chkBox = chkBoxRange.Parent.CheckBoxes.Add(0, 1, 1, 0)

    With chkBox

        'Set the position of the checkbox based on the cell
        .Top = c.Top + c.Height / 2 - chkBox.Height / 2
        .Left = c.Left + c.Width / 2 - chkBox.Width / 2

        'Set the name of the checkbox based on the cell address
        .Name = c.Address

        'Set the linked cell to the cell with the checkbox
        .LinkedCell = c.Offset(0, 0).Address(external:=True)

        'Enable the checkBox to be used when worksheet protection applied
        .Locked = False

        'Set the caption to blank
        .Caption = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A10").Value

    End With

    'Set the cell to the default value
    c.Value = chkBoxDefault

    'Hide the value in the cell with Number Formatting
    c.NumberFormat = ";;;"

Next c

End Sub
```

How do I correct the mismatch error?

//UPDATED Script

```
Sub CreateCheckBoxes()

'Declare variables
Dim c As Range
Dim chkBox As CheckBox
Dim ansBoxDefault As Long
Dim chkBoxRange As Range
Dim chkBoxDefault As Boolean
Dim i As Long

'Ingore errors if user clicks Cancel or X
On Error Resume Next

'Use Input Box to select cells
Set chkBoxRange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select cell range", _
    Title:="Create checkboxes", Type:=8)

'Exit the code if user clicks Cancel or X
If Err.Number <> 0 Then Exit Sub

'Use MessageBox to select checked or unchecked
ansBoxDefault = MsgBox("Should the boxes be checked?", vbYesNoCancel, _
    "Create checkboxes")
If ansBoxDefault = vbYes Then chkBoxDefault = True
If ansBoxDefault = vbNo Then chkBoxDefault = False
If ansBoxDefault = vbCancel Then Exit Sub

'Turn error checking back on
On Error GoTo 0

'Loop through each cell in the selected cells
For Each c In chkBoxRange
    i = i + 1

    'Create the checkbox
    Set chkBox = chkBoxRange.Parent.CheckBoxes.Add(0, 1, 1, 0)

    With chkBox

        'Set the position of the checkbox based on the cell
        .Top = c.Top + c.Height / 2 - chkBox.Height / 2
        .Left = c.Left + c.Width / 2 - chkBox.Width / 2

        'Set the name of the checkbox based on the cell address
        .Name = c.Address

        'Set the linked cell to the cell with the checkbox
        .LinkedCell = c.Offset(0, 0).Address(external:=True)

        'Enable the checkBox to be used when worksheet protection applied
        .Locked = False

        'Set the caption to blank
        .Caption = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i).Value

    End With

    'Set the cell to the default value
    c.Value = chkBoxDefault

    'Hide the value in the cell with Number Formatting
    c.NumberFormat = ";;;"

Next c

End Sub
```

Thanks!....................................................................................................................................................

Comment: please tell us which line is throwing the error.

Comment: not sure what it is you are trying to achieve here, but at a quick glance, this does not look right - .Caption = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A10").Value - you can't assign value of a Range of cells to a Text property. To set caption to blank, use .Caption = vbNullString

Comment: I would like as the checkboxes are inserted by the script to pull the caption from certain cells on a separate worksheet. This way we only have to maintain a list of cells and the checkboxes will regenerate each time we add to the list.

Comment: @ScottCraner the caption line .Caption = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A10").Value   I think that tsdn is correct, maybe I need assistance with creating a loop???

Comment: declare an iterator variable (i.e. Dim i as long), add a line to increment the i value inside your for each loop (i.e. i = i + 1), then update this ".Caption = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A10").Value" to something like this ".Caption = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i).Value"

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CreateCheckBoxes()

'Declare variables
Dim c As Range
Dim chkBox As CheckBox
Dim ansBoxDefault As Long
Dim chkBoxRange As Range
Dim chkBoxDefault As Boolean
Dim i As Long

'Ingore errors if user clicks Cancel or X
On Error Resume Next

'Use Input Box to select cells
Set chkBoxRange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select cell range", _
    Title:="Create checkboxes", Type:=8)

'Exit the code if user clicks Cancel or X
If Err.Number <> 0 Then Exit Sub

'Use MessageBox to select checked or unchecked
ansBoxDefault = MsgBox("Should the boxes be checked?", vbYesNoCancel, _
    "Create checkboxes")
If ansBoxDefault = vbYes Then chkBoxDefault = True
If ansBoxDefault = vbNo Then chkBoxDefault = False
If ansBoxDefault = vbCancel Then Exit Sub

'Turn error checking back on
On Error GoTo 0

'Loop through each cell in the selected cells
For Each c In chkBoxRange
    i = i + 1

    'Create the checkbox
    Set chkBox = chkBoxRange.Parent.CheckBoxes.Add(0, 1, 1, 0)

    With chkBox

        'Set the position of the checkbox based on the cell
        .Top = c.Top + c.Height / 2 - chkBox.Height / 2
        .Left = c.Left + c.Width / 2 - chkBox.Width / 2

        'Set the name of the checkbox based on the cell address
        .Name = c.Address

        'Set the linked cell to the cell with the checkbox
        .LinkedCell = c.Offset(0, 0).Address(external:=True)

        'Enable the checkBox to be used when worksheet protection applied
        .Locked = False

        'Set the caption to blank
        .Caption = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i).Value

    End With

    'Set the cell to the default value
    c.Value = chkBoxDefault

    'Hide the value in the cell with Number Formatting
    c.NumberFormat = ";;;"

Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).